# Problem with adding a new Team through PowerShell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to automate the creation of a new Microsoft Teams team through Powershell. I'm quite far and the script I made creates a new team and the channels, the only problem I have is that every time I run the script I get this error, which is kind of logical, but I can't fix it. Can anybody help me?

```
New-Team : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'DisplayName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\Microsoft Teams\NewTeamV2.ps1:10 char:39
+     $GroupID = (New-Team -DisplayName $d.TeamDisplayName -Template $d ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Team], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.TeamsCmdlets.PowerShell.Custom.NewTeam
```

I'm using a loop to go through the CSV file:

[image: CSV File]

```
#Connection
$cred = Get-StoredCredential -Target 'Teams'
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -Credential $cred

#Importeren of data
$data = Import-csv comma.csv

#Loop for creation of teams and channels
foreach ($d in $data) {
    $GroupID = (New-Team -DisplayName $d.TeamDisplayName -Template $d.Template).GroupID
    New-TeamChannel -GroupId $GroupID -DisplayName $d.ChannelDisplayName    
}
```

Comment: Yes, i want multiple channels for the same team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `New-Team` only for those rows where the team name is set. For the following rows, the `$groupID` stays unchanged, so `New-TeamChannel` will assign the channel to the *same* team as the previous one.

Let me know if this works for you

```bsh
foreach ($d in $data) {
    if ($d.TeamDisplayName) {
        $GroupID = (New-Team -DisplayName $d.TeamDisplayName -Template $d.Template).GroupID
    }
    New-TeamChannel -GroupId $GroupID -DisplayName $d.ChannelDisplayName    
}
```